# Image and div inline alignment

Tags: html, css

How to align the `div` inline with the `image`.The text is supposed to appear on the right side of the page `inline` with the image.

```html
**EDIT**
<div>
<img src='/media/site.png' onclick="javascript:getfunc('/home/')" </img>

</div>
<div  style="padding-right:50px;padding-top:2px;float:right">
Login
</div>
```

Comment: `<font style="...` *\*sigh\**

Comment: Is this the actual code? The image tag is messed-up. Deprecated mark–up aside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to align that right floating div with the image you should place that div BEFORE the img... i.e.

```
 <div style="padding-right:50px;padding-top:2px;float:right">
     Login
 </div>
 <div>
     <img src='/media/site.png' onclick="javascript:getfunc('/home/')" alt="this attrib should be always present" />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont u just put image in div then float whatever direction you want.

```
 <div>
 Login
 <img src='/media/site.png' onclick="javascript:getfunc('/home/')" style="float:left;" />
 </div>
```